# How to prove the optimality of this greedy algo?

Tags: algorithm, proof

Given N integers. Each of these numbers can be increased or decreased once by no more than given positive integer L. After each operation if any numbers become equal we consider them as one number. The problem is to calculate cardinality of minimal set of distinct integers.

Constraints: N <= 100, L <= 3200, integers are in the range [-32000, 32000]

Example: N = 3, L = 10
11 21 27

1) increase 11 by 10 => 21 21 27
2) decrease 27 by 6 => 21 21 21

The answer is 1.

Algo in C++ language:

```
sort(v.begin(), v.end());
// the algo tries to include elements in interval of length 2 * L
int ans = 0;
int first = 0; 
for(int i = 1; i < N; ++i) {
    if(v[i] - v[first] > 2 * L) { // if we can't include i-th element 
        ans++;                    // into the current interval   
        first = i;                // the algo construct new 
    }
}
ans++;
printf("%d", ans);
```

I try to understand why this greedy algo is optimal. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Don't you mean "correctness" of the algorithm rather than "optimality" ?

Comment: If you can prove (separately) that it never overestimates and never underestimates, then you have proved it always gives the right answer.  I suggest starting with the first: Is there any situation in which it can overestimate?

Comment: By "optimal," do you perhaps mean time complexity in terms of the number of arithmetic operations?

Comment: @nodakai By "optimal" I mean why greedy algo gives the right answer.

Comment: This algorithm does not work (or your problem description is inaccurate). Counterexample: [1, 10, 11, 2] and L=5. The optimal answer is 2 but your algorithm returns 3.

Comment: @VincentvanderWeele The above code correctly returns 1 http://ideone.com/RDANYe All of the four integers can be modified to 6 by at most 5 increments/decrements

Comment: @nodakai my bad, I missed the hidden sort at the beginning. Then it obviously works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reframed, we're trying to cover the set of numbers that appear in the input with as few intervals of cardinality `2*L + 1` as possible. You can imagine that, for an interval `[C - L, C + L]`, all numbers in it are adjusted to `C`.

Given any list of intervals in sorted order, we can show inductively in `k` that, considering only the first `k` intervals, the first `k` of greedy covers at least as much of the input. The base case `k = 0` is trivial. Inductively, greedy covers the next uncovered input element and as much as it can in addition; the interval in the arbitrary solution that covers its next uncovered input element must be not after greedy's, so the arbitrary solution has no more coverage.